# How to make sure an extra field shows up in my Django admin form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following code:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['extra_field'] = forms.CharField(
            label=_('Extra field'),
            max_length=255
        )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'


class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    extra = 0
    model = MyModel
    form = MyModelForm
```

The extra field I added does not show up in my form. Please note, the extra field is not a field present in the database. It is just something specifically for this form. How can I make sure that the extra field shows up in my form, along with all the other database fields automatically? I don't want a way where I have to manually mention every field in the self.fields attribute. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to override the **`__init__()`** method, just put the field as *regular fashion* as,

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(label=_('Extra field'), max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = Session
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Yeah that works. I put it in init because I wanted it to have a default value based on whether the object existed or not. Any idea how I can do this using your method?

Comment: can you put that logic in OP?

Comment: Nvm it should be a separate question.